# How hierarchical and FE models estimate the number of level 2 groups

Tags: multilevel-analysis, fixed-effects-model

I'm estimating a hierarchical/multilevel model and a standard fixed effect model for a cross-national survey, with level 2 set at the country level.

When I look at the outputs for these models however, I see that the hierarchical model lists a slightly higher n for the level 2 groups than the FE model.

I think this is probably something to do with the theory on both of these models, rather than something specific to the package (I'm using R), hence why I'm asking this here. I would be very grateful for some pointers on this.

I was thinking it perhaps had something to do with how missing data is handled, or if there are very few respondents in some level 2 groups (as is the case for my data), but I'm not sure.

Comment: What package are you using? Some of them may drop singleton clusters but not necessarily clusters with 2 or more observations. Also, typically random effects models are fit using maximum likelihood that can work with missingness in the outcome provided there is no missingness in the predictors.

Comment: Hey, I'm using alpaca for the FE and lme4 for the hierarchical model. There aren't enough clusters with only one observation to fully explain the difference between the two, but I guess that might at least partly explain it? Both models are glm logit models, so as far as I understand are using MLE

Comment: Interesting. I might try fitting the models with `plm` to see if using the same backend, so to speak, leads to similar sample size differences. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/A_plmPackage.html

Comment: Ok, thanks that's a good idea - I'll give it a go